# normal map shows up slightly offset on mesh, but only in cycles render view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, normals, normal-map

I am following a tutorial to make an anvil in blender 2.9.1.  I have 2 different meshes, a sculpted high poly mesh, and a low poly, regular mesh.  I made sure both objects were on the exact same spot when I baked them.  the normal map turned out great, and when I plugged it into the normal in the material viewer, it looked just fine.  My problem is that when I go into render mode, the normal map suddenly changes, and it shifts a few inches to the left around the whole mesh, making it look really weird. (See image below)
[image]
but when I go back to material view, it looks perfectly fine.

Here is a picture without materials on it so you can better see my problem:
[image]
I want these normals to show up on the corners of the mesh instead of where it is now.  I know that the problem is not UV based because I have already checked my UV's.

here is my node setup:
[image]

(sorry it might be kind of hard to see)

does anyone know why this is happening?  And better yet, how to fix it?  any help is appreciated! :)

(PS, I will give the link to my file below)

[image]

Comment: Please pack the image files.

Comment: what does that mean?  sorry, I'm not the most experienced with blender yet

Comment: See [packed data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.90/files/blend/packed_data.html?highlight=packed-data)

Comment: ah, I get it now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on.  I discovered that since I had a mix shader that was mixing 2 normals together, and one of the image textures for the normals was conneted to a mapping node, so because of the mix shader, the mapping effected the other normalmap as well.